# Upload large file on server is this possible by create firefox addon

Tags: file-upload, firefox-addon

I want to upload large video file. for that i want to create firefox addon. Is this possible by create firefox addons to upload large files on my server.
or is there any other way to upload large files on server.
please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If you are POSTing the data to the server as application/x-www-form-urlencoded then you should base64 encode it using btoa() and include it as one of the POST parameters in the request body (i.e. the string passed to XMLHttpRequest.send()):

```
postbody = "body=" + btoa(fileContents);
xhr.send(postbody);
```

If you are just downloading the file and uploading it right away, you might as well keep it in memory since you're presumably going to load it into memory anyway in order to base64 encode the contents.

Well if you're reading the file into memory then you should need an nsIFile at all. You can just download it using XMLHttpRequest and use responseText, uploading it in the way I described in the answer. If you do have an nsIFile then yes, that snippet describes how to read from it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are wanting to upload via HTTP.

If so, the upload limit is usually decided by the server-side software.  This affects both the maximum size and the length of time you have to upload it.

Without a server capable of taking an upload in chunks and reassembling it, you are limited in ways you can't get around through software.

If you want to upload via FTP on the other hand, there are a lot of options... look at [FireFTP](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireftp/).

Comment: Hi Jeremy,
I have to upload on cross domain and i want to upload in chunk. And I have decided uploaded limit on server.
Can i do this in firefox addons. If yes then how 
give me some link or more

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to make it remotely possible to give you more advice.  Questions range from "Are you controlling the software that runs on the server, or is it run by someone else" to "Are you looking for a solution that would work for you -- or work for the general public."  Nor have you answered if there is FTP/SFTP/etc available on the server for file uploading.

Answer (score 0):

I have made firefox addons for fileupload.

I integrate jquery file upload.

I create widget. In the widget I made panel. In panel I create separate web page for file uploading. And panel is calling that page.

For more information you can mail me at chetansinghal1988@gmail.com